# Midi controlled metronome?

Tags: piano, midi, metronomes

For piano practice (Roland RD 88), I would like a metronome I can control with MIDI foot pedal/ switches (Roland FC-300). It's most important to me to adjust the tempo with an expression pedal CC, and it would be nice to switch between time signatures with PC messages.

My first preference is to control the RD-88 metronome directly, but I can't figure that out. Secondly, would be to run something on my MacBook, thirdly on an iPad.

Anybody have any ideas? Free and simple is best ;).

Later tonight I might set up some basic "songs" on Drambo (a bell for the bar start, a click for each beat), and then try to connect midi learn and tempo and program change input all together. I would rather do something with the MacBook because all the cables are hooked up to that anyway. If I have to buy Logic, I can do that but I don't really want to (yet).

Comment: I wonder the close votes, what's the motivation ? This does not ask for recommendation, but for a way to do something.

Comment: How fluent are you with programming ? The keyboard metronome will probably accept a midi clock. So a small computer program using for instance midio for python can transform a bunch of CCs into a midi clock

Comment: Very fluent in programming but would rather not do it after work. I might handroll it, but I would use supercollider I think.

Comment: You might edit to say more about your ultimate goal of how you're going to use it. If the point is simply that your performance changes tempos, but your plan of the tempos you want and the bar numbers between them is set in stone, then a simple static click track will do. If you need to accommodate improv breaks of variable lengths, or the tempo choices need to be flexible, that's another matter.

Comment: @Tom: I don't see much to justify your expectation, that if a device has a midi-plug then the metronome should be accessible through it.

Comment: @guidot actually, after looking it up, it does not seem to have a midi in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Drummer's Pulse" claims to do it online. It seems to require Chrome and WebMIDI.

[image: screenshot]

When you search for it, follow the Cache and select text-only (to avoid endless clicking on buttons etc.) it claims:

```
MIDI

Link your MIDI hardware controllers to the following functions by pressing the buttons and following the instructions:
General
Start/Stop
Tap
Next Sound
BPM
BPM
BPM - 10
BPM + 10
BPM - 1
BPM + 1
BPM Announcement
Toggle BPM Announcement
Beats
Beats
Beats - 1
Beats + 1
Volumes
Master
Whole note
Quarter note
Eighth note
Sixteenth note
Triplet note
External
External (MIDI control change)
Sends the value of this fader to an external application (e.g. Toontrack ezDrummer which is capable to control the volume by MIDI). Notice: You have to install a MIDI loopback software (e.g. loopMIDI by Tobias Erichsen).

Port:   Channel: All 12345678910111213141516   #: 0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119

Sorry, but your browser doesn't support WebMIDI.

These browsers support Web MIDI natively:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=midi
```

There may be more. I tried as search term:

```
midi controlled metronom tempo signature
```